# phpmyadmin: how to select a default database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way to select a default database when entering phpmyadmin ?

I have 20 databases and I would like to create some shortcuts like

Better if I can choose it with an url parameter such as:

?defaultDatabase=database1

Answer (score 3):

The url parameter for the database name is 'db'. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-access-directly-to-database-or-table-pages.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'normal' url to open phpMyAdmin was:

```
https://yourMyPhpAdmin.com/
```

. . . then you could go directly to a **specific database** with:

```
https://yourMyPhpAdmin.com/sql.php?db=yourDBname
```

. . . or directly to **SQL view** in that database with:

```
https://yourMyPhpAdmin.com/db_sql.php?db=yourDBname
```

. . . or directly to **Browse Table** view with:

```
https://yourMyPhpAdmin.com/sql.php?db=yourDBname&table=yourTableName
```

I save a lot of time by keeping a set of one-click links to database sections/tasks that I use frequently.  You can even supply login credentials - if your webhost has the [option](https://serverfault.com/questions/144095/phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-lamp-login-without-a-password-is-forbidden-by-configurat) enabled. Also, if your webhost the ophasn't disabled this (like mine has), you could even supply your **login credentials** with:

`&pma_username=youUserName`
`&pma_password=yourPassword`

You can find more parameters by keeping an eye on the eye on the url querystring while navigating the site, or there's more information [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#which-parameters-can-i-use-in-the-url-that-starts-phpmyadmin):

---

> ## 4.8 Which parameters can I use in the URL that starts phpMyAdmin?
>
> When accessing phpMyAdmin, you can use the `db`, `pma_username`, `pma_password` and `server` URL parameters. The `server` parameter can contain either the numeric *host index* (from $i of the configuration file) or one of the *host names* present in the configuration file. Using `pma_username` and `pma_password` has been tested with the `‘cookie’` auth_type.
>
> For example, a direct login URL can be constructed as:
>   `https://example.com/phpmyadmin/?pma_username=user&pma_password=password`
>
> ---
>
> [image: i] <sup>**Warning:** If you don't already know why this is a **bad** idea, then you ***really*** shouldn't use that last tip!</sup>

If you wanted to get ***really*** fancy, a quick addition to your `.htaccess` file would allow you to use direct urls like below.  (Details [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#faq1-34))

- `http://server/phpMyAdmin/yourDatabase` ,or,
- `http://server/phpMyAdmin/yourDatabase/yourTable` ,or,
- `http://server/phpMyAdmin/yourDatabase/yourTable/yourScript`

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same task by setting $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config' and some other parameter?